# How to map an array of object property names to an array of the values that the names point to in a given object

Tags: typescript

```
const obj = { wheels: 4, lights: 2, doors: 4 }

someMapFunction(obj, { 
  props: ["wheel", "lights"], 
  format: (wheels, lights) => `${wheels}-${lights}` // "4-2"
})
```

How would I type `someMapFunction` so that typescript knows that `props` can only be keys of `obj` and that the `format` function will take all of the values that the `props` array values point to within `obj`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would define the function like this:

```
function someMapFunction<
  T, 
  K extends (keyof T)[]
>(obj: T, propsAndFormat: { 
  props: [...K], 
  format: (...args: {
    [I in keyof K]: T[K[I]]
  }) => string 
}) {
  return null!
}
```

It has two generic parameters `T` and `K`. `T` describes the type of the object passed as `obj` while `K` is a tuple of keys of `T`. When we declare the parameter type of `props`, we use the [variadic tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) syntax `[...K]` to infer `K` as a *tuple* and not and *array* since the order is important.

For `format`, we declare it to be a [*rest parameter*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#rest-parameters) where the order and type of elements are described by a tuple. To create this tuple, we can map over the elements `I` in the tuple `K` and use them to extract the corresponding type of `T`.

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvGB3AFgUzwBsIAuGAFgBoZCBLAcxylJgCZqATEEAJxfJgBfALAAoMWIBmAVzDAotcDAggAtngCyAQwAOAMVnzFYADxiYMACrVzMANIw8ADyh4wHCDAAUAazwBPEEkrAEoAbQBdMQA%20LwREMmsYHR4QHQgAQXc9XlUtKDJMWxS0ljCAOkq7CJtRC0lc-LIvSvKtHnoWdFsLMIBJGFowGD9A4OrEsLt%20iKi6oRDUaOUoHiH6GDFBRe75njwoaR5hsGlCQgBCLYlRFXVtfUMFcDikaiL5kvSyMIAiXAIxF%201F%20dEYzF%20NU28waPDyBW8AKIEGoYKYEEWKGWAAMACToJHEQQAWnxaOYgmxWxCQA)

Comment: Thank you! I was so close. My mistake was that I thought for [I in keyof K], the I was current key in K. But since K is an array it's an index!!

Comment: I asked a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74049790/how-to-type-a-function-that-accepts-an-object-and-an-array-of-objects-that-refer. Thanks again.