# How to type a function that accepts an object and an array of objects that reference the object props and values?

Tags: typescript

Here is an example below and the problem is highlighted in the comments.

```
function formatObjectValues<T, K extends keyof T>(
  obj: T,
  formatConfig: {
    prop: K;
    format: (arg: T[K]) => string;
  }[]
) {
  return formatConfig.map(({ prop, format }) => {
    return format(obj[prop]);
  });
}

const obj = { wheels: ["good", "bad", "great", "new"], lights: 2, doors: "new" };

formatObjectValues(obj, [
  {
    prop: "doors",
    format: (doors) => `${doors}`,
    // PROBLEM: doors inferred as being string | number | string[] but should only be string
  },
  {
    prop: "wheels",
    format: (wheels) => `${wheels}`,
    // PROBLEM: wheels inferred as being string | number | string[] but should only be string[]
  },
  {
    prop: "lights",
    format: (lights) => `${lights}`,
    // PROBLEM:  inferred as being string | number | string[] but should only be number
  },
]);
```

How does the type signature of `formatObjectValues` need to change to fix the problems mentioned above?

Answer (score 1):

OK I think I got it.

```
type Formatter<T, K> = K extends Extract<keyof T,string> ? { prop: K, format: (val: T[K]) => string } : never

function formatObjectValues<T,K extends Extract<keyof T, string>>
(
  obj: T,
  formatConfig: Formatter<T, K>[]
) {
  return formatConfig.map(({ prop, format }) => {
    return format(obj[prop]);
  });
}

const obj = { wheels: ["good", "bad", "great", "new"], lights: 2, doors: "new" };

formatObjectValues(obj, [
  {
    prop: "doors",
    format: (doors) => `${doors}`,
  },
  {
    prop: "wheels",
    format: (wheels) => `${wheels}`,
  },
  {
    prop: "lights",
    format: (lights) => `${lights}`,
  },
]);
```

Comment: Might need to uh, edit the comments in the code so they don't confuse a skimmer :)